# How to filter list action in Rails using named routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resources, filter, railscasts, named-routing

Given I have two models: `company` and `location`. A `company` has many `locations`.
I found [Ryan Bates' Named Routes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/34-named-routes) very interesting.
So I added resources for each of my model in `routes.rb`.

```
resources :companies
resources :locations
```

This enables me to generate links based on named routes like `<%= link_to "Companies", companies_path %>` which results in `http://localhost:3000/companies`.

Now I want to filter the list of `locations` based on the `company` they belong to. Before working with named routes I accomplished this by add a link like the following.

```
<%= link_to "Locations for this company", { :controller => 'locations', :action => 'list', :company_id => company.id } %>
```

Here I pass the `company_id` to the `LocationsController` which filters the location in its `list` action.

```
def list
  @locations = Location.order("locations.id ASC").where(:company_id => @company.try(:id))
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option:

```
  resources :companies do
    get :list, :controller => :locations
  end
```

will produce this route:

```
   company_list GET    /companies/:company_id/list(.:format) {:action=>"list", :controller=>"locations"}
```

And this provides you, then, with a `company_list` helper method.

This, however,

```
  resources :companies do
    get :list, :controller => :locations
    resources :locations
  end
```

Will *also* provide you with a `company_locations` helper that points,instead, to the `index` action on the LocationsController instead of the `list`.

```
 company_locations GET    /companies/:company_id/locations(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"locations"}
```

The latter is more RESTful, but you're the developer, so you get decide which naming helps you more.

The downside is that most of the actions/helpers on your Locations controller are now dependent on having a :company_id or instantiated Company model attached to them.

**EDIT**

3rd option:

```
resources :companies do
  get :list, :controller => :locations
end
resources :locations
```

This seems best, since other than the 'company_list' route, you don't claim to have much need for locations being filtered by company.

Comment: Works! Though, I have another unfiltered link pointing to `locations_path`. It does not show any `location`. This is caused to what I defined in the controller. How can I ensure both filtered and unfiltered results using the `list` action of the locations controller?

Comment: Thank you. I stay with my first choice since I also want to create new locations that are associated with a company. I use `new_company_location_path` to keep the association.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your location model needs to do, I would suggest using nested resources;

```
resources :companies do   
    resources :locations 
end
```

Then do a rake routes, which will give you all sorts of new, nicer routes like:

company/id/locations

Comment: Thanks, I have chosen this option.